# Django AllAuth KeyError at /accounts/login/ 'BACKEND'

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-settings, keyerror, django-login

When I log in with the wrong/right credentials I don't just get a simple form error or login I go a full debug error page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCUOJ.jpg

I have all auth fully installed and provider Google is working for signup and login. I'm also doing this on the allauth standardized login form and URL. Please let me know if I should post any more info besides the pictures.

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': { 
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static',
            },
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter"


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',

    # Django Specific
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    # django-allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    # Make sure 'collectfast' is in INSTALLED_APPS, before 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    'collectfast',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Packages / Modules
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'rest_framework',
    'storages',
    'flatpickr',

    # Local apps
    'portfolios',

]

SITE_ID = 3

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dash'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = 'dash'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the collectfast package https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast and the custom backend settings were interfering with the django-allauth package. I can comment this part out when the app is live and only uncomment it when I need to collect static.

Not the best fix but a step in the right direction.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        # Your default cache
    },
    'collectfast': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 5000,
        }
    }
}
```